# In mongodb source code, What is the usage of _view_private?

Tags: mongodb

I am reading mongodb source code. I have a question about memory-map-file.There are _view_write and _view_private in class DurableMappedFile. The _view_write is used for saving a pointer of mapped. The _view_private also save a pointer of mapped, but the mapped pointer is MAP_PRIVATE type. The MAP_PRIVATE is copy-on-write. I don't know What occasion will be used pointer of MAP_PRIVATE.
Note:The class DurableMappedFile is defined in durable_mapped_file.h/cpp.MongoDB source code version is 2.6.12.

Comment: Please include a link to the source file in question.

Comment: @Thilo,I have added include file and source code version.

Comment: @Thilo,I know this file.I don't understand why need MAP_PRIVATE.I want to look a situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that we have a private copy on write view of the memory mapped file is that we cannot risk the OS writing modified areas of the memory-mapped file back to disk before the entire write transaction (WriteUnitOfWork) is complete and written to the journal. Only after the journal is durable on disk (synced) is it safe to start writing the data to disk. We do that by copying the data back on the write view. Then periodically we remap our private view so we don't keep duplicate copies indefinitely.

See [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/2bd286acef2fdb035f1d45253f6e6e4c24a2dc04/src/mongo/db/storage/mmap_v1/dur.cpp#L30-L52) for more detail.

Doing updates this way ensures that replaying the journal after a hard crash (unclean shutdown) will leave the data in a consistent state.